# JS-Need shape to show on map when onhover in table element, without having to write a JS for each instant

Tags: javascript, external, onmouseover, imagemap

I found a script online where I can hover a text and a shape shows on an imagemap. It works, but only for that one instant. Can I use a JS that serves individual instances, so I won't have to write an individual JS that references each insant?
My texts are arranged in a table.

here's my JS:

```
<HEAD>.....
 <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
    $('#squidheadlink').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#squidhead').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $('#squidhead').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
});
</script>


<BODY>......
<map.....
<area id="squidhead" href="#" shape="rect" coords="680,55,730,110"  alt="Octoface"     data maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.6}'>
<area id="xxx" href="#" shape="circle" coords="298,552,10" alt="Octoface"  data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"ff0000","fillOpacity":0.6}'>
</map>
</div>
<DIV ID="header" STYLE="position:absolute; top:450px; left:20px; width:1490px;  height:225px;">
<table class="tftable" border="0">
<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th><th>Header 3</th><th>Header 4</th><th>Header  5</th><th>Header 6</th><th>Header 7</th><th>Header 8</th><th>Header 9</th><th>Header 10</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><a id="squidheadlink" href="#">gyrex</a></td>
<td><a id="xxxlink" href="#">xxx</a></td>
```

AS YOU CAN SEE ABOVE I have a second item to highlight, which in the "area id" references the following code, which is a duplicate of the "squidhead" section with the adjustment of having a different name to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
    $('#xxxlink').mouseover(function(e) {
        $('#xxx').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
        $('#xxx').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
});</script>
```

MY Question is, is there a way to manipulate the javascript so it can be used just once for the whole ARRAY of items in the table that are used to highlight different areas on the map/image?

The "id" items reference their appropriate JS script, so that I am forced to write an individual JS for every instant, which will be many...

THE resolved script, thanks to @levi:

OK, after MUCH reworking of the code, it works...the above gentleman was spot on...there so many variables to work on, geez...the final script:
       $(function() {
           $('.map').maphilight();
          $('.tftable td a').each(function () {
      var areaId = '#' + this.id.replace('link', '');
        $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
           $(areaId).mouseover();
        }).mouseout(function (e) {
          $(areaId).mouseout();
        }).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
     });
    });

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        $('.map').maphilight();
       $('.tftable td a').each(function () {
    var areaId = '#' + this.id.replace('link', '');
    $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
        $(areaId).mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        $(areaId).mouseout();
    }).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
});
 </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to apply the code to multiple instances:

```
 $('.tftable td a').each(function () {
    var areaId = '#' + this.id.replace('link', '');
    $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
        $(areaId).mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        $(areaId).mouseout();
    }).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer. Back to the drawing board and sort out the details...

Comment: Well, after more research, I got lost. Don't know if the answer is an appendage to the original JS or a stand-alone JS. Any further help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Its simple. This piece of code would replace all your code below `$('.map').maphilight();`. Instead of separately defining the mouseover events for each element, this collects all links inside the table, and for each link, it binds the relevant mousover events.

Comment: Note: the above code assumes the naming convention used in your original code. ie: the associated area on the map has the same `id` as the link, minus the word `link`. If you change your classes or IDs you may need to update this code accordingly.

Comment: If you have further trouble, please post a JSfiddle link with your complete code.

Comment: Ok, Levi, I tried to follow your instructions, this is what I have after implementing your recommendations---http://jsfiddle.net/4Ydu3 and it does not work. Also left out all of CSS...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tell from that link whats wrong, as you are missing the images, and js scripts. Do you have a live link I can look at?

Comment: http://dcalvitti.webs.com/plant/INDEX.html  old and http://dcalvitti.webs.com/plant/INDEXwithPOLY.html  your mods

Comment: There is a syntax error on your page. Your code is missing the final `});`. Check your browsers error console, and you will see these errors.

Comment: Found the problem after making modifications, and after running the debug program in IE I found and fixed the error you point out. After debugging again I ended up with no errors. However, the script still doesn't work. In the original, you can hover over the link in the table and the shape shows up in the imagemap. You can't do that now. What happens is that the shape shows up when you hover over the hot spot. BTW, looking for work?

Comment: OK, after MUCH reworking of the code, it works...the above gentleman was spot on...